# Importing Android Source code: Red exclaimation mark + "Cannot be resolved to a variable" error

Tags: android, eclipse, variables, open-intents

I have downloaded this [GitHub source code](https://github.com/openintents/notepad) and have extracted it and imported into eclipse using `"Import existing Android code".`

However when I open the code, one priject has a `Red Exclaimation Mark error`on it, and the other "test" project contains code that gives a general error of `"Cannot be resolved to a variable".`

Note: I cannot show a screen shot as I do not have a high enough reputation.

I am getting the error on any code with:

```
org.openintents.distribution
```

E.g:

```
@Smoke
    public void test000Eula() {
        String accept = getAppString(org.openintents.distribution.R.string.oi_distribution_eula_accept);
        String cancel = getAppString(org.openintents.distribution.R.string.oi_distribution_eula_refuse);
        boolean existsAccept = solo.searchButton(accept);
        boolean existsCancel = solo.searchButton(cancel);

        if (existsAccept && existsCancel) {
            solo.clickOnButton(accept);
        }
    }
```

How can I solve both the red exclamation mark ad the "cannot be resolved error?" Any help would be great as I am very new to Android!

Comment: Is your package `org.openintents.distribution`? I suggest your remove all `org.openintents.distribution` and manually import `R`

Comment: No that is not the package name, the package name is org.openintents.notepad.test ?

Comment: Please note that I am also getting this error in relation to both projects: "Unable to resolve target 'android-15'"

Comment: What is this **@Smoke**?? It looks like **garbage**.

Comment: Im not sure what @smoke is, what do you mean garbage?

Answer (score 0):

Does solo.searchButton() return boolean?? If not you have to write your function to return true or false.

I am guessing thats why you are getting the error cannot be resolved because you cannot resolve a string value to boolean.

If u can post your complete code that will be more helpful.